# Trouble replacing strings in Java

Tags: java, regex, split

If i have this String:

```
String line = "This, is Stack; Overflow.";
```

And want to split it into the following array of strings:

```
String[] array = ...
```

so the array contains this output:

```
["This",",","is","Stack",";","Overflow","."]
```

What regex expression should i put into the split() method ?

Comment: My bad. Misread the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split your input according to the spaces or the boundaries which exists between a word character and a non-word character, vice-versa.

```
String s = "This, is Stack; Overflow.";
String parts[] = s.split("\\s|(?<=\\w)(?=\\W)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

`\s` matches any kind of whitespace character, `\w` matches  a word character and `\W` matches a non-word character.

- `\s` matches a space character.
- `(?<=\\w)` Positive look-behind which asserts that the match must be preceded by a word character (*`a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_`*).
- `(?=\\W)` Positive look-ahead which asserts that the match must be followed by a non-word character(*any character other than the word character*). So this `(?<=\\w)(?=\\W)` regex matches only the boundaries not a character.
- Thus splitting the input according to the matches spaces and the boundaries will give you the desired output.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rO3kJ1/6)

**OR**

```
String s = "This, is Stack; Overflow.";
String parts[] = s.split("\\s|(?<=\\w)(?=\\W)|(?<=[^\\w\\s])(?=\\w)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

**Output:**

```
[This, ,, is, Stack, ;, Overflow, .]
```

Comment: Could you just explain what the regex expression means ? Because there's a lot of weird syntax in there...

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with this pattern:

```
\\s+|(?<=\\S)(?=[^\\w\\s])|(?<=[^\\w\\s])\\b
```

it trims whitespaces and deals with consecutive special characters, example:

With `;This, is Stack; ;; Overflow.`

you obtain: `[";", "This", ",", "is", "Stack", ";", ";", ";", "Overflow", "."]`

But obviously, the more efficient way is to not use the split method but the find method with this pattern:

```
\\w+|[^\\w\\s]
```